# jquery get only first checkbox of a tr

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I want to check if the first checkbox in a tr is selected not all the checkbox that is found in this tr.

For the time being i have this code :

```
var b = false;
$j('#tb1 td input:checkbox').each(function(){ 
      if($j(this).is(':checked')){
    b = true;
      }
});
```

this check if there is at least one checkbox check
but if i add this to my selector :

```
$j('#tb1 td input:first:checkbox').each(function(){ 
      if($j(this).is(':checked')){
    b = true;
      }
});
```

it check for only the first row not for all the rows and only the first checkbox.
How can i achieve this by using the "first" selector ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: can u create jsfiddle...

Comment: do you want to validate whether all the first checkboxes are checked or whether any one of them is checked

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try

```
var b = false;
$j('#tb1 tr').find('input:checkbox:first').each(function(){ 
    if(this.checked){
        b = true;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try it

```
 var b = false;
  $j('#tb1 tr input:checkbox:first').each(function(){
    if(this.checked){
      b = true;
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `jquery` code is wrong, you are using the correct `selector` but in wrong place..try this

```
$j('#tb1 td input:checkbox:first').
```

More infor about `:First` is [here](http://api.jquery.com/first/)

Answer (score 0):

You are doing correct but placing of selector is wrong.

**change**

```
$j('#tb1 td input:first:checkbox').
```

**to**

```
$j('#tb1 td input:checkbox:first').
```